# Has anyone made a seed project using Angular 2 with Koa js?

Tags: angular, koa

I'd like to make a seed project where I have Angular 2 for the front end and Koajs as the backend. All i've seen so far is KOAN but it uses Angular 1. If anyone has done it, please share. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I laid eyes on this library: [Angular 2 ESNext Starter](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter). It uses Koa, ES6/Babel and not TypeScript, webpack bundling, livereload, linting with Airbnb style guide.